# Groovy, get list of current week and last 2 weeks

Tags: groovy

I got a domain work with id, day, list day from January to now.
I get the current time by code:

```
def current = new Date()
```

So, I'd like to get list day from last 2 weeks, included this week, then I used the following code but it doesn't work.

```
def getWeek = current.Time - 13 (13 is 2 week + today)
```

Please help me solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure I understand, but you should be able to use a Range:

```
def current = new Date().clearTime()

def listOfDays = (current - 13)..current

listOfDays.each { println it }
```

That prints:

```
Wed Apr 09 00:00:00 BST 2014
Thu Apr 10 00:00:00 BST 2014
Fri Apr 11 00:00:00 BST 2014
Sat Apr 12 00:00:00 BST 2014
Sun Apr 13 00:00:00 BST 2014
Mon Apr 14 00:00:00 BST 2014
Tue Apr 15 00:00:00 BST 2014
Wed Apr 16 00:00:00 BST 2014
Thu Apr 17 00:00:00 BST 2014
Fri Apr 18 00:00:00 BST 2014
Sat Apr 19 00:00:00 BST 2014
Sun Apr 20 00:00:00 BST 2014
Mon Apr 21 00:00:00 BST 2014
Tue Apr 22 00:00:00 BST 2014
```

If you mean you want the entire 2 weeks before the current week AND the current week, you could do:

```
def current = new Date().clearTime()

int currentDay = Calendar.instance.with {
    time = current
    get( Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK )
}

def listOfDays = (current - 13 - currentDay)..(current + 7 - currentDay)

listOfDays.each {
    println it
}
```

Which prints:

```
Sun Apr 06 00:00:00 BST 2014
Mon Apr 07 00:00:00 BST 2014
Tue Apr 08 00:00:00 BST 2014
Wed Apr 09 00:00:00 BST 2014
Thu Apr 10 00:00:00 BST 2014
Fri Apr 11 00:00:00 BST 2014
Sat Apr 12 00:00:00 BST 2014
Sun Apr 13 00:00:00 BST 2014
Mon Apr 14 00:00:00 BST 2014
Tue Apr 15 00:00:00 BST 2014
Wed Apr 16 00:00:00 BST 2014
Thu Apr 17 00:00:00 BST 2014
Fri Apr 18 00:00:00 BST 2014
Sat Apr 19 00:00:00 BST 2014
Sun Apr 20 00:00:00 BST 2014
Mon Apr 21 00:00:00 BST 2014
Tue Apr 22 00:00:00 BST 2014
Wed Apr 23 00:00:00 BST 2014
Thu Apr 24 00:00:00 BST 2014
Fri Apr 25 00:00:00 BST 2014
Sat Apr 26 00:00:00 BST 2014
```

Comment: I made it, hang on, I have one more question, on current date, how can we count date of current week? eg: week starts from Sunday to Saturday. Then, today is Monday, when days of week = 2, if Tuesday, day of week is 3. Please help, thanks

Comment: You mean like: `int day = Calendar.instance.with { time = current ; get( Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK ) }`?

Comment: Here is my idea, I'd to show information of last 2 weeks and current week, then to day is Monday, I use current day - 16 (16 means last 2 weeks) to find total day, then next step, that was use for only Monday, if current is Thursday, how can I calculate? that's my point.