# Grails get day of current week and last three weeks

Tags: groovy

I got a domain work with id, day
Day shows value from Match to current.
I need to find the list of current week and last two weeks
Ex: today is Monday (04/22) then what I need is:

- Week1: 06-12 April
- Week2: 13-19 April
- Current week: 20-26 April.

Please helps, thanks.

Comment: Did my update to your previous question help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/23216269/6509

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posted here for posterity:

```
def current = new Date().clearTime()

int currentDay = Calendar.instance.with {
    time = current
    get( Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK )
}

def listOfDays = (current - 13 - currentDay)..(current + 7 - currentDay)

listOfDays.each {
    println it
}
```

Prints:

```
Sun Apr 06 00:00:00 BST 2014
Mon Apr 07 00:00:00 BST 2014
Tue Apr 08 00:00:00 BST 2014
Wed Apr 09 00:00:00 BST 2014
Thu Apr 10 00:00:00 BST 2014
Fri Apr 11 00:00:00 BST 2014
Sat Apr 12 00:00:00 BST 2014
Sun Apr 13 00:00:00 BST 2014
Mon Apr 14 00:00:00 BST 2014
Tue Apr 15 00:00:00 BST 2014
Wed Apr 16 00:00:00 BST 2014
Thu Apr 17 00:00:00 BST 2014
Fri Apr 18 00:00:00 BST 2014
Sat Apr 19 00:00:00 BST 2014
Sun Apr 20 00:00:00 BST 2014
Mon Apr 21 00:00:00 BST 2014
Tue Apr 22 00:00:00 BST 2014
Wed Apr 23 00:00:00 BST 2014
Thu Apr 24 00:00:00 BST 2014
Fri Apr 25 00:00:00 BST 2014
Sat Apr 26 00:00:00 BST 2014
```

Comment: or `(current - 13 - currentDay).upto(current + 7 - currentDay) { println it }` in Groovy 2.2 ;-)

Comment: @dmahapatro Ahh, but that doesn't get you a list of Dates ;-)

Comment: Agree, but ultimately if the idea is to iterate over the list and do stuff, then the closure param in `upto()` automatically does that incrementing per day. :)